# AddOrder for 2 columns in FluentHibernate

Tags: sql, fluent-nhibernate

I would like to know the criteria for the Following SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM PageDetails WHERE PageRoom_Id = 4 Order By SentDate DESC, Id DESC
```

Currently I am using the criteria like below:

```
var criteria = unitOfWork.CurrentSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(PageDetails))
               .CreateAlias("PageRoom", "pageRoom")
               .Add(Restrictions.Eq("pageRoom.PageRoom_Id", pageRoom.PageRoom_Id))
               .AddOrder(Order.Desc("SentDate"));
```

How to add one more ordering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var criteria = unitOfWork.CurrentSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(PageDetails))
               .CreateAlias("PageDetails", "pageDetails")
               .Add(Restrictions.Eq("pageDetails.PageRoom_Id", pageRoom.PageRoom_Id))
               .AddOrder(Order.Desc("SentDate"))
               .AddOrder(Order.Desc("Id"));
```

Comment: No I didn't get any error message, but the sequence of result is not same as we run the sql query.

Comment: This should definitely work...can you find out the SQL that is generated by this criteria? Also, I have noticed that you are using "PageRoom" in the code but in your query you say you want to search in the "PageDetails" table - could this be causing the problem? I will update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Yes it worked the issue was for the case sensitiveness for the column thanks a lot...